# "The file .master does not exist"

Tags: c#, .net, iis, master-pages, publish

I have a website which uses .net framework 4.5.
Using Visual Studio 2013, I have no issues to run it.
However, when I publish it, I get the following error message: "the file '/Views/Shared/Admin.Master' doesn't exists.", but it does exists.

```
Linha 1:  <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Admin.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<dynamic>" %>
Linha 2:  
Linha 3:  <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
```

Any idea about it, if I need to do something before publishing, or if I need to configure something in IIS?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: try replacing `~` with `..`   `"~/Views/Shared/Admin.Master"` as `"../Views/Shared/Admin.Master"`

Comment: I tried, but I'm still getting the same error. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I faced the same issue, the application build and run correctly on visual studio 2013, but give that error when publishing.

To fix that I changed the build action of the master-page from **None** to **Content**

Answer (score 0):

Probably IIS issue.
Go to your IIS, go to your website.
Once there, in the IIS tab, find Authentication. Open it.
Enable ASP.NET Impersonation.

It happens to me sometimes. Is a problem of rights